# Numbers are not visible in Python Plotly Funnel

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am plotting a funnel in plotly using python, and even though I have adjusted the font size to 18, the numbers at the really bottom for the red part are very small and arent visible. I am wondering how I can adjust it so that the numbers are on the outside like they are for the green part of the funnel

[image]

Comment: You can try setting the parameter `textposition = "outside"` but this will make the text for each stage of the funnel appear on the outside

Comment: @DerekO do you know how to put the text on the outside left, because outside just puts it on the right side

Comment: Please actually show the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to achieve what you want. You could try to hide the text and use annotations, but this isn't easily generalizable as you would need to know ahead of time which values are too small for the text to fit legibly inside of the chart.

The best solution I can think of is to use the `constraintext = "outside"` parameter to force the text to stay the same size regardless of the width for each stage of the funnel, although the text on the left will still be inside the chart.

As you pointed out, my original suggestion of using `textposition = "outside"` doesn't work properly (as it places the left text on the right side of the chart), and I believe that this is a bug in the Plotly library.

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    x = [135, 62, 47, 20, 2, 1],
    constraintext='outside',
    textfont=dict(
        family="sans serif",
        size=18,
        color="white"
        )
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    orientation = "h",
    y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    x = [298, 145, 120, 87, 11, 2], 
    constraintext='outside',
    textfont=dict(
        family="sans serif",
        size=18,
        color="black"
        )
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]